# Creating a new column based on unique ID with values in r

Tags: r

For each of these IDs, I would like to create a new column called Age populated with the values `0 to 5 for each ID` (r=0:5) as shown below.

Data Frame

```
ID         
1124
1123
```

Desired Outcome

```
ID   Age
1124  0
1124  1
1124  2
1124  3
1124  4
1124  5
1123  0
1123  1
1123  2
1123  3
1123  4
1123  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R version:

```
df = data_frame(ID = c(1124, 1123))
expand.grid(ID = df$ID, Age = 0:5)

##      ID Age
## 1  1124   0
## 2  1123   0
## 3  1124   1
## 4  1123   1
## 5  1124   2
## 6  1123   2
## 7  1124   3
## 8  1123   3
## 9  1124   4
## 10 1123   4
## 11 1124   5
## 12 1123   5
```

This is sorted differently from the `tidyr::expand` result.

**EDIT**

As @thelatemail suggested, you can do the following to avoid renaming `df`

```
expand.grid(c(Age=list(0:5), df))
```

or

```
merge(df, list(Age=0:5))
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a `data.table` example:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # Convert df to a data.table.
df[, do.call(CJ, list(ID = ID, Age = 0:5))]
```

For large data sets, one might want to benchmark the various methods.

Comment: Without renaming `df` -  `expand.grid(c(Age=list(0:5), df))` or cartesian join it - `merge(df, list(Age=0:5))`

Comment: @thelatemail Great suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `tidyr::expand`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data_frame(ID = c(1124, 1123))

df %>%
    expand(ID, Age = 0:5)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
      ID   Age
   <dbl> <int>
 1  1123     0
 2  1123     1
 3  1123     2
 4  1123     3
 5  1123     4
 6  1123     5
 7  1124     0
 8  1124     1
 9  1124     2
10  1124     3
11  1124     4
12  1124     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
your_data_frame %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Age = (1:n()) - 1)
```

This works also if you have more than 6 `Age` values per `ID`.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that there's currently only 1 row per ID in the dataframe, I don't think this answer works in that case.

Comment: I see. In that case I misunderstood @Marius